# OpenCV 4.7.0 Unhandled Exception - xfeatures2d SURF::create

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-stitching

I am currently using OpenCV v4.7.0 with C++. I have built and installed the OpenCV extra modules, and I have updated my linker settings, include directories, and additional library directories accordingly in my Visual Studio 2019 project properties.

I am following this tutorial directly: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d6f/tutorial_feature_flann_matcher.html. The project builds without any errors or warnings. I get a runtime error when creating the SURF detector. The line seen below is when the error occurs:

`Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( minHessian );`

The error can be seen below:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC8A95051C in vs_src.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000F9CD70E680.

I have tried catching the `cv::Exception`, but there is no information that comes with this error. What can I do to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try printing values from `cv::Exception` class? There is `what()` method and also many public members which can help printing useful info. If it doesn't print anything, better raise an issue in OpenCV repository on Github and ask them to fix it.

Comment: Have you built contrib module with the flag `OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE` enabled? See this [thread](https://answers.opencv.org/question/201938/how-can-i-set-opencv_enable_nonfree-cmake-option-and-rebuild-the-library-in-function-create/)